# SVN-to-git mirror include all branches

Tags: git, svn, version-control

The time has come to move a well-loved SVN repository to git.

My first task, which I need some help with, is figuring out how to put a git face on the SVN repo by creating some kind of one-way mirror. The idea is that, for the time being, all developers will continue committing to SVN as they have been, but we'll start switching over all of the tooling (Jenkins, bug trackers, etc) to pull from a git mirror. **No commits will be made to the git mirror**.

This seems like it should be relatively straightforward, but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to make all of the svn branches available upon cloning. So far I have a repository I've `git-svn clone`d which I'll use as a workspace for a cron job to periodically pull new changes. I've also got an empty bare repository which is where the tools will actually be pulling from. And the "Jenkins" machine has a clone of `my_mirror` in the diagram below.

```
 +---------+                    +-----------------+
 | Jenkins |--------------------|    my_mirror    |
 +---------+                    | (git bare repo) |
                                +-----------------+
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |
                                +-----------------+
                                |   my_workspace  |
                                | (git-svn clone) |
                                +-----------------+
                                          |
                                          |
                                 +---------------+
                                 |    SVN Repo   |
                                 +---------------+
```

The trouble I'm having is that I can't figure out a way of taking all of the SVN branches which `git branch --all` shows as `remotes/origin/*`, and push them to the bare git repository in such a way where they're visible by a git clone. I suppose it's possible to have the cron job that's going to pull in new changes just checkout and run `git svn rebase` for every branch, but is there a more straightforward way of doing what I want? The repo is quite large and the host machine takes quite a long time to checkout each branch.

I'm using a small test repo with a `trunk` and a single branch `1.0.0`, but the real thing has a few dozen branches.

```
[@my_workspace] $ git svn --version
git-svn version 1.9.1 (svn 1.8.8)
[@my_workspace] $ git clone --stdlayout myrepos.com/SVNRepo my_workspace && cd my_workspace
[@my_workspace] $ git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/1.0.0
  remotes/origin/trunk

#######
[@my_mirror] $ git clone --mirror my_workspace.com/my_workspace my_mirror && cd my_mirror
[@my_mirror] $ git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/1.0.0
  remotes/origin/trunk

#######
[@jenkins] $ git clone my_mirror.com/my_mirror workspace && cd workspace
[@jenkins] $ git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I have tried adding `my_mirror` as a remote to the `my_workspace` git-svn checkout and using `git push --mirror my_mirror` but no success with that. I've also tried creating an empty `--bare` repo, adding it as a remote in `my_workspace`, and pushing to it with `git push --mirror my_bare_repo` but no joy.

Comment: I could be biased but wouldn't it be easier to use SubGit for that? It translates SVN branches to Git branches. This would also eliminate the need for intermediate "my_workspace" and hand-written scripts. Full disclosure: I'm one of SubGit developers

Comment: @DmitryPavlenko The chances are the OP has never heard of SubGit, so if you think it will solve their problem, why not write an answer showing how they'd use it for this scenario?

Comment: In my web-searching I *have* come across SubGit, and I suppose that "pay somebody to do it" or "buy a new tool" are legitimate answers, but this feels like something I should be able to do with just a shell, git, git-svn, and cron without a ton of extra effort.